# Prevent photoshop from cropping 100% transparent areas of PNGs when placing. Or prevent hard edges on placed png files

Tags: adobe-photoshop

If I place a png file that has intentional transparent space surrounding the image into a photoshop document photoshop seems to remove that surrounding space.  This wouldn't bother me too much, except that what tends to happen is that if I resize the placed png after it has been placed I end up with hard edges where photoshop has not antialiased beyond the edge of the now cropped image, resulting in an ugly hard edge.

I end up having to work around this by, for example, adding an *almost* totally transparent pixel beyond the visible edge of the image I'm placing, within the source document, to force photoshop not to crop to the visible pixels, and thus include the antialiasing on the edge as it does everywhere else (to make the resized image look nice).  This creates new problems though, such as causing photoshop to include that almost invisible pixel when applying effects such as glow/shadow etc.

Is there a way to prevent this phenomenon when placing PNG files?

[image]

Edit: Source PNG added by request (however it was created purely to illustrate my point. This happens with any placed image with transparency)

[image]

Comment: Can you share the source PNG?

Comment: The source png was just an example to illustrate the point. It happens with ANY placed png file (maybe other formats too but usually use png files).  It's just a simple red circle saved as a png in photoshop. I have added it anyway.

Comment: The problem is I can't replicate your issue. When I Place a similar PNG, it looks fine, no chopped off pixels. [See example](https://imgur.com/R5FCgga).  Are you rescaling the PNG after placing? That might cause issues.

Comment: Note the PNG you shared has a pixel above the circle, so this isn't your source PNG. Looks like the one you modified?

Comment: This doesn't seem right at all. I could sort of imagine and accept that there's a bug or something that causes 1px shift... but if I'm seeing that right, simply opening the file eats 10 transparent pixels from the top, right, and left and I would assume it would eat all transparent pixels from the edges, not just a set amount. My first guess would be that you have a script or maybe an Action triggered every time a document is opened and it does: `Image > Trim > Transparent pixels` at the very least... and perhaps something more.

Comment: @BillyKerr yes I am rescaling. I mentioned that in the question.  I do often need to rescale placed pngs to get them to the desired size in the thing I'm working on.  The png I shared is the modified one.  It can still be used to test though by checking left/right/bottom of the circle.  I have no actions or scripts.  It happens on more than one computer (CC allows two installations of PS)

Comment: @MrVimes - I'm also using Photoshop CC. Still can't really replicate the problem as you show it, but if you resize an image smaller, then zoom in to see pixels, it's never going to look good.  Maybe set your zoom to 100%.

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand that resizing smaller reduces the quality.  But this literally only ever happens to the edges of resized pngs....  I only zoomed in to make the problem clearer for this question.  It still looks bad not zoomed in. If I add the 'fix' pixel it always has acceptable antialiased edges instead of hard edges.

I suspect my solution is just going to have to be to reduce my expectations of quality :)

Comment: To add... you can see it doesn't *always* happen. For example in my example it's happened on the top and left, but not on the right.    I appreciate your help trying to replicate this.  I will try to get used to it (I am a bit of a perfectionist and I'm using PS for creating stuff for public consumption)

Comment: I've ran into this before and used the same fix as you. Pad the image with transparent pixels all around. The problem is photoshop doesn't want to go beyond your desired size even just to antialiase. What I do not get is your second part of problems. Usually outlines and shadows only apply to opaque pixels and transparent padding doesn't matter.

Comment: @MrVimes - I totally get the perfectionist thing, but you really do need to stop pixel peeping. It's rarely useful. Always view raster images at 100%, then you can decide if there's a problem.  Another thing to be aware of is that small circles in raster images are always going to be problematic because of the very nature of pixels.  Maybe think about using vector software instead of Phtotoshop.

Comment: @Miro padding the image with transparent pixes doesn't work for me because PS seems to ignore any transparency beyond the non-transparent edges.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments here it seems like something isn't working properly for you. Whenever I place an image with transparent padding it is placed with the same padding as the original. No trimming. Even if the entire png is a blank 200x200 image, it will place as 200x200.

Here's what a logo looks like with padding before placing:

[image: svelte logo]

Can you try to place [this same .png logo](https://codingthesmartway.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/logo_svelte.png) and take screenshot right before confirming placing?

Comment: Apologies for the delay responding.  I have just tried at home.  Before place the padding remains, but after place it shows a bounding box as if cropped (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzYQR.jpg)  However, I cannot replicate the problem I've been having.   I would try at work (where I use PS most for this type of work) but where I live just went into coronavirus lockdown so I won't be able to go back there for at least 3 weeks!   Anyway it *might* be an issue with that copy of PS, or the gfx card or drivers.

Comment: p.s. I have moved on from worrying about this as suggested by @BillyKer , but I wanted to do you the courtesy of responding.

Comment: Edit... It seems hit and miss.  I did try resizing your logo again, and did get a hard edge.  I guess I am just being very anal about it though.

Comment: Sometimes it is a real problem.  I am working with a logo, it has actually resulted in the bottom of some text being chopped off.  I don't think it's too anal to want my 'o' s to be complete circles.  The source png file has LOADS of space below the 'woodford' but photoshop chops it off because there are no pixels.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GVxE.jpg